# How to query records based on row_num and one of the column value?

Tags: sql-server, sequence, row-number

```
Rownum  Status
1         2
2         1
3         3
4         2
5         3
6         1
```

The condition is to query records appear before the first record of `status=3` which in the above scenario the expected output will be rownum = 1 and 2.
 
In the case if there is no `status=3` then show everything.

I'm not sure from where to start hence currently no findings

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, then you can use window version of `SUM` with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT Rownum, Status
FROM (
  SELECT Rownum, Status, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
          OVER 
           (ORDER BY Rownum) AS s
FROM mytable) t
WHERE t.s = 0
```

Calculated field `s` is a *running total* of `Status = 3` occurrences. The query returns all records before the *first* occurrence of a `3` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7577e/1)